# pegar hora de array com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código:

```
var fhora = function(horamin, horamax){
    var horas = ["11:20", "04:40", "22:30", "07:00"];
    return horas;
};
```

como faço para que so me retorne as horas que estão entre 05:00 e 23:30?

```
fhora("05:00", "23:30");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

- Cria uma função para converter `hh:mm` em minutos
- Cria outra função para comparar o minimo e máximo
- Passa também as horas a escolher (a array com todas as opções) à função que compara. Assim ficas com uma função pura e não tens efeitos secundários no código.

Exemplo:

```js
var horas = ["11:20", "04:40", "22:30", "07:00", "23.:45"];

function horasParaMinutos(str) {
  var horas = str.split(':').map(Number);
  return horas[0] * 60 + horas[1];
}

var fhora = function(horamin, horamax, arr) {
  horamin = horasParaMinutos(horamin);
  horamax = horasParaMinutos(horamax);
  return arr.filter(function(hora) {
    hora = horasParaMinutos(hora);
    return hora >= horamin && hora <= horamax;
  });
};

var res = fhora("05:00", "23:30", horas);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Publiquei minha resposta e não havia visto que a sua também utilizava o `filter`. Você converteu os valores para minutos ao invés de simplesmente comparar as strings por algum motivo em especial?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss converti as strings porque gosto de comparar numeros com o _Type_ correto, e porque é mais seguro para quem puder ler este post e vá comparar `7:0` e `6:15` :)

Comment: @Sergio essa função tambem serve para esse caso?? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213822/ajuda-com-filtro-em-json-com-jquery/213828#213828

Comment: @Newtech sim, só tens de mudar a lógica de `horasParaMinutos` para gerar um timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa, utilizando o [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), seria:

```js
function fhora (horamin, horamax)
{
    return ["11:20", "04:40", "22:30", "07:00", "23:45"].filter(hora => hora >= horamin && hora <= horamax);
};

console.log(fhora("05:00", "23:30"));
```

Pois, como os horários são *string* e estão no formato 24h, uma simples comparação entre *string* já é suficiente para identificar se determinado valor está no intervalo desejado.