# Ajuda para filtrar um JSON com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtro, filter

Tenho esse código que filtra um objeto JSON:

```
var filtrar =  function (horamin, horamax)
{
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
  let result = data.filter(item => {
    let voos = item.trecho[1].voo.filter(voo => {
      var time = horasParaMinutos(voo.hrDuracao);
      console.log(horamin);
      return time >= horamin && time <= horamax;
    });
    item.trecho[1].voo = voos;
    return voos.length > 0;
  });
  return result;
};
```

Esse código filtra somento o `trecho[1].voo`. O meu problema e que quando ele retorna false ou sem nenhum dados ele não exibe o `trecho[0].voo`.

Vou deixar um exemplo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/abjj8gkd/1/) para melhor entender.

Exemplo se no slide ranger estiver selecionado a hora minima de 08:10 ele retorna esse json:

```
[
    {
        "dsObservacao": null,
        "trecho": [
            {
                "sqTrecho": 1,
                "voo": [
                    {
                        "dtPartida": "20170720 11:20",
                        "dtChegada": "20170720 16:40",
                        "hrDuracao": "00:30"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "sqTrecho": 2,
                "voo": [
                    {
                        "dtPartida": "20170727 14:15",
                        "dtChegada": "20170727 17:40",
                        "hrDuracao": "08:10"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Se a hora for maior que 08:10 ele não retorna nada `[]` quando era para retornar assim:

```
[
    {
        "dsObservacao": null,
        "trecho": [
            {
                "sqTrecho": 1,
                "voo": [
                    {
                        "dtPartida": "20170720 11:20",
                        "dtChegada": "20170720 16:40",
                        "hrDuracao": "00:30"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Resumindo**: O que preciso fazer e filtrar somente o `trecho[1]` e manter o `trecho[0]`.

Comment: E por quê ele deveria retornar `trecho[0].voo` se o filtro é aplicado somente em `trecho[1].voo`? Aliás, é bom você sempre referenciar a [discussão que gerou o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213822/5878) em questão pois pode ser útil para quem for responder. Por exemplo, nessa pergunta você não colocou o que é a função `horasParaMinutos`. Aliás, **qual é a diferença entre as perguntas exatamente?**

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse filtro filtra somente o objeto `trecho[1].voo`. No `trecho[0].voo` tambem tem dados mas não está sendo filtrado. O problema e que quando o filtro não achar nenhum objeto que esteja dentro da hora seleciona ele retorna `[]` e não retorna os dados que está em `trecho[0].voo`. Ou sejá se não houver dados em `trecho[1].voo` ele não exibe o `trecho[0].voo`. o `horasParaMinutos` e somente para converter a hora para minuto para poder verificar se e maior ou menor que a hora recebida pelos parametros horamin e horamax que está em minutos

Comment: Sim, porque você está aplicando o filtro em todos os elementos baseado no valor de `trecho[1]`. Se este não possuir valor, retornará falso para todas as posições da lista e ela ficará nula. Você só deve aplicar o filtro utilizando `trecho[1]` quando `item` referir-se ao trecho 1.

Comment: cara, ficou meio confuso o que vc quer... você quer filtar só o trecho[1] e, caso não tenha resultado, mostre o trecho[0] ou vc quer filtrar todos os trechos e, caso não tenha resultado, mostre o trecho[0] ??

Comment: @J.Guilherme quero filtrar so o trecho[1] e manter o trecho[0].

Comment: Queres filtrar a duração da viagem (`hrDuracao`), é isso?

Comment: @Sergio quero filtrar a `hrDuracao` somente do `trecho[1]` e manter o `trecho[0]`.

Comment: Ok, então e terás um slider com duração (0 até tipo 24h) e depois filtrar, certo?

Comment: editei minha resposta, veja se funciona como esperado

Comment: @Sergio sim. um slider de 0 a 24h e depois filtrar somente o trecho[1].voo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que precisas é:

```
var filtrados = json.aPesquisa.map(obj => {
    return obj.trecho.map(trecho => {
        return trecho.voo.filter(voo => {
            return horasParaMinutos(voo.hrDuracao) <= duracao
        });
    });
});
```

Isso filtra os voos que têm duração superior a `duracao`. Um exemplo a funcionar seria assim:

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbvqrxr4/))

```js
var legenda = document.getElementById('legenda');
$("#slider").slider({
  animate: true,
  step: 1,
  min: 0,
  max: 1440, // 1440 são a quantidade de minutos num dia
  values: [0],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var val = ui.values[0];
    mostrarTrechos(json, val);
    legenda.innerHTML = [Math.floor(val / 60), val % 60].map(h => h < 10 ? '0' + h : h).join(':');
  }
});

function horasParaMinutos(str) {
  var horas = str.split(':').map(Number);
  return horas[0] * 60 + horas[1];
}

function mostrarTrechos(json, duracao) {
  var filtrados = json.aPesquisa.map(obj => {
    return obj.trecho.map(trecho => {
      return trecho.voo.filter(voo => {
        return horasParaMinutos(voo.hrDuracao) <= duracao
      });
    });
  });
  $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(filtrados, null, 2));
}

const json = {
  "aPesquisa": [{
      "dsObservacao": null,
      "trecho": [{
        "sqTrecho": 1,
        "voo": [{
          "dtPartida": "20170620 11:20",
          "dtChegada": "20170620 16:40",
          "hrDuracao": "01:20"
        }]
      }, {
        "sqTrecho": 2,
        "voo": [{

          "dtPartida": "20170627 04:10",
          "dtChegada": "20170627 07:40",
          "hrDuracao": "03:20"
        }, {
          "dtPartida": "20170627 14:15",
          "dtChegada": "20170627 17:40",
          "hrDuracao": "05:45"
        }]
      }]
    },

    {
      "dsObservacao": null,
      "trecho": [{
        "sqTrecho": 1,
        "voo": [{
          "dtPartida": "20170720 11:20",
          "dtChegada": "20170720 16:40",
          "hrDuracao": "00:30"
        }]
      }, {
        "sqTrecho": 2,
        "voo": [{

          "dtPartida": "20170727 04:10",
          "dtChegada": "20170727 07:40",
          "hrDuracao": "03:00"
        }, {
          "dtPartida": "20170727 14:15",
          "dtChegada": "20170727 17:40",
          "hrDuracao": "08:10"
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#legenda {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#sliderHolder {
  padding: 100px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ddf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  background: #aaf;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  top: -12px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  outline: none;
  background: #aab;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover,
.ui-slider-handle:active {
  background: #889;
}

.ui-disabled .ui-slider-range {
  background: grey;
}

.ui-disabled .ui-slider-handle {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.ui-disabled,
.ui-disabled .ui-slider-handle {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sliderHolder">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <div id="legenda"></div>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

substitua o seu primeiro filtro por um forEach.

```
var filtrar =  function (horamin, horamax)
{
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
  let result = data.forEach(item => {
    let voos = item.trecho[1].voo.filter(voo => {
      var time = horasParaMinutos(voo.hrDuracao);
      return time >= horamin && time <= horamax;
    });
    item.trecho[1].voo = voos;
  });
  return result;
};
```

segue um exemplo levemente adaptado, para que se torne completo.

```js
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
let Voo = function (partida, chegada) {
  this.partida = new Date(partida);
  this.chegada = new Date(chegada);
  this.partida.setMinutes(this.partida.getMinutes() - offset);
  this.chegada.setMinutes(this.chegada.getMinutes() - offset);
}

Object.defineProperty(Voo.prototype, "duracao", {
  get: function () {
    var date = new Date(this.chegada.getTime() - this.partida.getTime());
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + offset);
    return date;
  }
});

var getMinutes = function (voo) {
  var minutos = voo.duracao.getMinutes();
  var horas = voo.duracao.getHours();
  return horas * 60 + minutos;
}

var data = [
    {
        "dsObservacao": null,
        "trecho": [
            {
                "sqTrecho": 1,
                "voo": [
                    new Voo("2017-07-20T11:20", "2017-07-20T16:40")
                ]
            },
            {
                "sqTrecho": 2,
                "voo": [
                    new Voo("2017-07-27T14:15", "2017-07-27T17:40")
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

var filtrar =  function (data, horamin, horamax)
{
  data.forEach(item => {
    let voos = item.trecho[1].voo.filter(voo => {
      var time = getMinutes(voo);
      return time >= horamin && time <= horamax;
    });
    item.trecho.splice(1, 1);
  });
  return result;
};

var result = filtrar(data, 8 * 60 + 10, 20 * 60 + 20);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Olá tudo bem? Teitei com seu código trocando o primeiro filter por forEach e coloquei um console.log() no result e está retornando undefined no console. Tem como dar uma olhada? **http://jsfiddle.net/abjj8gkd/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Pra resolvar o problema do trecho[0], é só obrigar o `filter` a retornar `true` quando o index for `0`. Algo parecido com isto:

```
var filtrar =  function (horamin, horamax)
{
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
  let result = data.filter((item,idx) => {
    if(idx === 0) return true;
    let voos = item.trecho[1].voo.filter(voo => {
      var time = horasParaMinutos(voo.hrDuracao);
      console.log(horamin);
      return time >= horamin && time <= horamax;
    });
    item.trecho[1].voo = voos;
    return voos.length > 0;
  });
  return result;
};
```

Desta forma, em todos os objetos de retorno o `trecho[0]` se mantem no result.

Comment: Tentei seu código mas não obtive o resultado esperado. ele me mostra somente o trecho[0] e não o trecho[1] junto

Comment: humm é verdade... editei o código pra corrigir esse comportamento